# Use glad loader in Qt app

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glew

I'm using Qt to write an OpenGL app. Until now, I was using QOpenGLFunctions_4_4_Core to get the OpenGL function pointers. However, I don't like to have to use inheritance in all the classes that call OpenGL functions.

To avoid this I tried to use the glad loader instead:

```
    void GLViewer::initializeGL() {
        qDebug() << "GL init";
        makeCurrent();
        if (gladLoadGL()) {
            // you need an OpenGL context before loading glad
            printf("I did load GL with no context!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        ...
```

However, it doesn't work, the loading fails telling me that there is no GL context.

Do you know why? Can I use an external GL loader instead of the Qt one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

gladLoadGL() returns 1 on success, but you are interpreting it as a failure.

Comment: Also, no need to call `makeCurrent` because this is done by Qt before calling `initializeGL` (and similar) functions. See [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qopenglwidget.html#initializeGL)